# Need help to find inverse function $f(x)=x+\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac x3\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

I need to find inverse of below function$$f(x)=x+\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac x3\rfloor$$ I saw its graph, it is an increasing function .
I can find inverse of $f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor$ or $f(x)=x-\lfloor -x \rfloor$ but get stuck on this problem . Can someone give a hint or an idea !?

Thanks in advance.

This link is the graph of $f(x)$https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sxopqslw23
I find fractional part of $y$ is equal to fractional part of $x$ because 
$$y=x+\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac x3\rfloor\\ \{y\}=\{x+\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac x3\rfloor \}\\=\{x\}+\{\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac x3\rfloor  \}=\\\{x\}+0$$ but where can I go from here  ?

Comment: The function isn’t surjective so to find the inverse you first need to nail down the image of $\mathbb R$ under $f$ so that you know what elements you can invert. I think determining the image will go a long way to determining the inverse.

Comment: $f^{-1}(11k)=6k $ if k positive integer.

Comment: For $f(x)=x+ \lfloor x \rfloor$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases} 
x-n & for \,\,\,\, 2n   \leq x < 2n+1 \\ 
n+1 & for \,\,\,\,2n+1 \leq x<2n+2
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ . Is this the kind of answer you are looking for ? (With $6$ cases for your specific question).